# Unable to retrieve data when using client-object model

Tags: 2013, csom, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a user that has read-permission to a specific list. On SharePoint **he can display** the list content. When I try to do the same using CSOM and his Login-Credentials I retrieve an error

Code-Snippet:

```
ClientContext userContext = new ClientContext("http://example.com/mysite");
userContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");

using (var context=userContext) {
  var list = GetListByTitle(context, "MyList");
  var listItems = list.GetItems(new CamlQuery());
  context.Load(listItems);
  context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

on the ExecuteQuery() I retrieve the error: `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException (Access denied)`

If I increase the users permission to admin-level, he **can** access the list using clientContext. (But I only want to give him read-permissions for that list)

Is there any client-specific permission that is needed to allow the user to retrieve the data using Client-Object-Model?

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the base permission **Use Remote Interfaces** to the permission level the user has been assigned.
You may also try to disable "Require Use Remote Interfaces permission" at the Web application level from the Central Administration, see e.g. [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/10/24/what-every-developer-needs-to-know-about-sharepoint-apps-csom-and-anonymous-publishing-sites/).